# CAML Query returns duplicate rows and populate data till my row limits is filled.

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

Hi I am using SharePoint 2007 to get calendar items using SharePoint Web Services. Below is the piece of query which I am using to fetch data. The problem here is my calendar has 1000 items and I have given row limit as 2000 so while returning data it is returning 2000 items instead of 1000 items. Unable to fix. Any lights!!!

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();        
           System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
            query.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
    "<Value Type=\"Counter\">0</Value></Gt></Where>";
            viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
            queryOptions.InnerXml = "";          

            XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems(ListTitle, "", query, viewFields, "2000", queryOptions, null);
```

Comment: What do you exactly get returned? All items twice or anything else?

Comment: Ok I checked again,, I am havinga  person group field which allows for multiple selection, If the field is having more than one person it is creating a different row all together with same attributes(id, unique id etc) but the person group field having one value each time. For example if person group field has 3 person names the xml generated has values like this

Comment: <z:row ows_Title="Carrom" ows_fRecurrence="0"  ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_EventDate="2011-08-09 12:15:00" ows_Players="113;#test3" ows_ID="3" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_UniqueId="3;#{BB74D6F8-F42F-4204-82E8-E2EAA6603AA3}" ows_FSObjType="3;#0" ows_Created="2011-08-09 12:06:46" ows_EndDate="2011-08-09 12:45:00" ows_FileRef="3;#Lists/Carrom Register/3_.000" ows_fAllDayEvent="0" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />

Comment: <z:row ows_Title="Carrom" ows_fRecurrence="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_EventDate="2011-08-09 12:15:00" ows_Players="199;#testname1" ows_ID="3" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_UniqueId="3;#{BB74D6F8-F42F-4204-82E8-E2EAA6603AA3}" ows_FSObjType="3;#0" ows_Created="2011-08-09 12:06:46" ows_EndDate="2011-08-09 12:45:00" ows_FileRef="3;#Lists/Carrom Register/3_.000" ows_fAllDayEvent="0" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />

Comment: <z:row ows_Title="Carrom" ows_fRecurrence="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_EventDate="2011-08-09 12:15:00" ows_Players="185;#test2" ows_ID="3" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_UniqueId="3;#{BB74D6F8-F42F-4204-82E8-E2EAA6603AA3}" ows_FSObjType="3;#0" ows_Created="2011-08-09 12:06:46" ows_EndDate="2011-08-09 12:45:00" ows_FileRef="3;#Lists/Carrom Register/3_.000" ows_fAllDayEvent="0" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />

Comment: If you have a people field which allows more than 1 person than you have to use ids to query your data as described here https://www.stum.de/2008/02/06/querying-the-person-or-group-field-using-spquery/

Comment: The Article doesn't mention about selecting Multiple Users field. That was the last question asked by the reader and is unanswered. I tried changing the person field format to Account Name still the result is same.:(